# Field extension $\mathbb F_p\subset E$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, extension-field

> Suppose there exists a field extension $\mathbb F_p\subset E$. 
>   **Question:** Is it possible that the degree is $[E:\mathbb F_p]=2$. And how many elemnts are in **E** then?

How can I proof such a question? Hints are welcome.

Comment: What is $L$ ? You can take $E=\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q=p^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[\Bbb{F}_{p^2}:\Bbb{F}_p]=2$ and the cardinal is $p^2$